# Simple way of Numbering my Assignments

Tags: numbering

When doing assignments by hand, I like to keep my work bound by invisible margins. For each problem, I like to number them on the left side of the problem, all numbering right hand flush to the invisible margin border.

To imitate this in LaTeX, I've written the following ( hopefully this will also clarify what I'm trying to explain.)

```
\newcommand{\problem}[1]{
\newlength{\len}\settowidth{\len}{ #1.}
\noindent\hspace{-\the\len} #1.
\let\len\undefined}

\problem{1a}
Whatever I'd like to write, such as solutions or problems and solutions
```

The idea is that when I'm about to start a problem, I shove the label left by it's width. This doesn't have to be the method of choice, and I was wondering if anyone more crafty in TeX than me would have suggestions. My approach has alignment issues and probably isn't robust under varying environments/layouts.

Criteria:

- Numbering scheme right aligned, to the left of the work (It'd be great if this degree of shift is manipulatable)
- The work should be not be indented
- Minimalistic approach! I'm not a big fan of creating super fat solutions that require external packages. This isn't a crazy design, and given how close I am without extra packages, I'm sure it can be done

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. It is much easier to help you if you post (close to working) code and this also usually helps to clarify what you want.

Comment: You shouldn't use \newlength inside such a command. This will use a skip register everytime you use it. Check the log and you will lines like `\len=\skip45 \len=\skip46 ...`. Your `\let` command doesn't prevent this, it only suppress the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pretty much do what you want just using `\llap`, which prints its contents to the left and leaves the "printing head" at the current location. You say that you do not want to use any packages but to show that it works I have used two packages:

- [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to print frames around the page
- [mwe](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) to print some random text using `\blindtext`.

Both of these packages are for demonstration purposes only and can be eliminated from the code below.

The MWE below produces

[image]

and here is the actual code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% only for demonstration purposes => page frame
\usepackage{mwe}% only for demonstration purposes => blind text
\newcommand{\problem}[2]{\noindent\llap{#1.\space}#2}

\begin{document}

  \blindtext

  \problem{1a} Whatever I'd like to write, such as solutions
  or problems and solutions

  \blindtext

  \problem{10c} Whatever I'd like to write, such as
  solutions or problems and solutions

\end{document}
```

Notice that I have defined `\problem` to take two arguments. This is just a sleight of hand to get rid of any extraneous space between `\problem{...}` and whatever comes next.

This said, it is probably better to define this as an environment, which would be used as

```
\begin{problem}{1a}
    Whatever I'd like to write, such as solutions or problems and solutions
\end{problem}
```

This copes better spacing issues and is more in keeping with the LaTeX paradigm. For example, the `\problem` macro above will not do what you want if it does not have an empty line above it. As an environment I would define this as:

```
\newenvironment{problem}[1]{\trivlist\item[\llap{#1.}]}{\endtrivlist}
```

This no longer needs the dummy second argument `#2` and it now does the right thing when the environment is not immediately preceded by a blank line. (Note that `trivlist` is a standard LaTeX environment and so does not require any additional packages!) The output is essentially the same as before.

Comment: You could use \ignorespaces instead of your dummy argument. The dummy argument would break if the following text is e.g. `{\verb+\x+}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer True, but I prefer the environment

Comment: Sure a list based solution is better.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. It brings a tear to my eye.

Comment: @CaptainMorgan Sorry, didn't mean to make you cry:)