# Error on `trivlist`'s `item` after Section Heading

Tags: lists

I am working on some lecture notes and I want some markup for questions. Currently I am thinking of a framed Q in the left margin like this:

[image: Left margin with a framed Q]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\experiment}[1]
{
\trivlist\item[\llap{\fbox{Q}$\;$}]%
\subsubsection*{#1}
\endtrivlist
}
\begin{document}
\experiment{First Question}
asdf
\experiment{Second Question}
%\subsection{Yet Another Heading}
%%asdf
%\experiment{Third Question}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the code will fail if executed after a section heading command, see the commented lines. Adding some text in between the heading and the question makes the error go away, but this is a feature I want: A heading and a question right below. Any ideas of how to achieve this?

---

Edit: The error message reads `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` However this does not provide me with a clue of how to procede.

Edit: From this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450493/simple-way-of-numbering-my-assignments/450494#450494) I gather that the missing empty line might be the source of the problem. not sure though

Comment: If you replace `\subsection{Yet Another Heading}` by `\subsection{Yet Another Heading}~` it works again. This is the usual problem with such hacks...

Comment: True, but the spacing is all wrong

Comment: Yes, another problem of that hack. If you use `\newcommand{\experiment}[1]
{
\subsubsection*{\llap{\fbox{Q}~~}#1}
}` it will be slightly less cumbersome.

Comment: No, I don't see an improvement. btw what do you mean by referring to it as a 'hack'?

Comment: I do not know what you mean but the atmosphere here is too heated to add another comment. All I wanted to do is to help. "hack" means that, to the best of my knowledge, you shouldn't put a section type command in a `trivlist`.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. I'll try something else than subsubsection

Comment: no document should be starting a section inside a list, and the sectioning and list macros are not designed for that, ideally they would give a specific nesting error but space for error checking was limited when the macros were written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. A `trivlist` environment should not contain sectional commands.
2. The commands `\trivlist` and `\endtrivlist` can only be safely used when defining *environments*, not commands.

Solution: just add the zero width box to the subsubsection title.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\experiment}[1]{%
  \subsubsection*{\makebox[0pt][r]{\normalfont\fbox{Q}\enspace}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\experiment{First Question}
asdf
\experiment{Second Question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After the discussion I had before (see above) I had realised that I wanted a modification of the subsubsection command, but still no clue of how to do it. Thank you @egreg